# Tor browser bundle gets uninstalled silently on restart on Windows 10.

Tags: windows-10, tor

Tor icon remains pinned in the start menu on restart but all of the installed files goes missing.

Comment: Extract file from installer with 7ZIP. Use it as standalone by running firefox.exe from the extracted files.

Comment: Apparently OP wants help with software getting uninstalled without consent on reboot. Currently it is tor-browser. In future it could be something else.